# Scalac hanging on phase typer of RegexParser

Tags: scala, parser-combinators, scala-2.11, scalac, scala-compiler

I have a scala program which among other things has a parser-combinator. This is done by extending `scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers`. I had developed it using Scala 2.10 and all was working fine.

Yesterday I upgraded my system to Scala 2.11.4, together with IntelliJ 14.02 (not that it matters).

However, whenever I try to compile this program now, `scalac` hangs during this phase:

`scalac: phase typer on MyParser.scala`

I changed absolutely nothing to this code, I can't understand why it is hanging or from where I should start. IntelliJ had a warning about postfix operators for parser expressions like `constants_def?` or `structure_def*`, where the `?` and `*` follow the token, and I added this line, because of the [SIP: Language Modularization Features](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/modularizing-language-features.html):

`import scala.language.postfixOps`

It didn't really have any effect and the problem is still the same.

How can I troubleshoot what is going on? I can't figure out from where to start understanding why the phase typer is just hanging indefinitely.

Comment: I would first suspect old build products in the IDE's workspace. Then I would try to reproduce with command-line scalac to eliminate the IDE. Then if I were curious, I'd use `-Ytyper-debug -verbose -Ydebug`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a workaround is to add an explicit type:

```
def da_gd : Parser[Expression with TimedCondition] =
  pref_timed_gd | da_gd_conjunction |
  (empty_temporal: Parser[Expression with TimedCondition])
```

A stack dump shows that it's figuring out the type of the expr, and `-Ytyper-debug` shows the vicinity.

Since nothing good happens after midnight, I'll stop there.

Comment: Thanks. So is it actually something that was broken in the 2.11 compiler?

Comment: Um, I dunno, I still haven't read the paper that Martin O. referenced on the bug report to the issue after this one. Well, it's clearly broken, but is it decidable?