# Scalac hanging in phase typer

Tags: scala, slick, scala-compiler

I am having a problem with 2.10.3 and code generated by Slick (Codegen).  It seems very similar to

[Scalac hanging on phase typer of RegexParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583857/scalac-hanging-on-phase-typer-of-regexparser/27698269#27698269)

Other files generated by Codegen work, but this one just hangs forever in "scalac: phase typer Foo.scala"

The only difference I can see is the number of columns in the table resulting in lots of vals and large cons'ed lists like this

```
def * = WordRootID :: WordID :: WordHeadID :: SynonymID :: PronunciationID :: Rank :: BNCFrequency :: CompassDifficulty :: DifficultyNormalized :: DifficultySourceCode :: COCARank :: PartOfSpeech :: AttributeNounProper :: AttributeNounGerund :: AttributePronounType :: AttributeVerbIrregular :: AttributeAdjectiveParticiple :: AttributeArticleType :: AttributeNumber :: AttributeLanguage :: AttributeIdiom :: AttributeMultiWord :: AttributeExcluded :: AttributePrivate :: en_DefinitionDeprecated :: en_QuizDefinitionDeprecated :: en_SourceDeprecated :: ja_WordDeprecated :: ja_SourceDeprecated :: ja_DifficultyDeprecated :: ko_WordDeprecated :: ko_SourceDeprecated :: zh_WordDeprecated :: zh_SourceDeprecated :: es_WordDeprecated :: es_SourceDeprecated :: pt_WordDeprecated :: pt_SourceDeprecated :: tr_WordDeprecated :: tr_SourceDeprecated :: vi_WordDeprecated :: vi_Source :: ReviewCode :: Active :: DateModified :: DateCreated :: en_QuizDefinitionDateModifiedDeprecated :: WordRootAssetID :: Locked :: AttributeStudiable :: WhiteListingStatus :: HNil
```

When I comment out most of fields and cut down the lists to something small like this the compiler finishes

```
def * = WordRootID :: WordID :: WordHeadID :: AttributeLanguage :: HNil
```

However, this is hardly an ideal way to code.  Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thank you very much
Peter

Comment: There are a number of comments in the Slick documentation regarding the upper limit of 22 fields. Did you read those comments and are they germane to your issue?

Comment: Try 2.10.4. There have been implicit search performance improvements.

Comment: Hi Bob, good thought but the 22 column limit has now gone away.  It was due to the limits of tuples, but now for very large tables, Codegen switches from tuples to HLists.  http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.3/code-generation.html

Comment: Thanks Cvogt.  What's the current state of 2.11?  Is it worth going all the way?

Comment: Expect some warnings in 2.11, but it is fully supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Cvogt, upgrading to 2.11 did the trick.  As you said, this is a problem with the 2.10.3 compiler and seems to be fixed now.